# Redux: Jest detects errors when dispatching an action from a Class method

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

I have the following Class to handle errors.

```
import { store } from 'redux/store';
import { openErrorMessage } from 'redux/slices/errorMessage';

export default class TestClass {
  errorReceived(errorMessage: string): void {
    store.dispatch(openErrorMessage({ message: errorMessage }));
  }
}
```

My goal is to dispatch an action from a non React component class like the `TestClass`.

Here is what's inside the errorMessageSlice.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export type ErrorMessageState = {
  isOpen?: boolean;
  message: string;
};

const initialState: ErrorMessageState = {
  isOpen: false,
  message: '',
};

const errorMessageSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'errorMessage',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    openErrorMessage(state: ErrorMessageState, { payload }: { payload: ErrorMessageState; type: string }) {
      state.isOpen = true;
      state.message = payload.message;
    },
    closeErrorMessage(state: ErrorMessageState) {
      state.isOpen = false;
      state.message = '';
    },
  },
});

export default errorMessageSlice;
export const { openErrorMessage, closeErrorMessage } = errorMessageSlice.actions;
```

And the rootReducer.

```
import { AnyAction, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { openErrorMessage } from './slices/errorMessage';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  // More Reducers
  errorMessage: errorMessageSlice.reducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state: ReturnType<typeof appReducer> | undefined, action: AnyAction) => {
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

When I execute `errorReceived` method from a client, it doesn't throw error.

But when I run tests with Jest, I have the following errors.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reducer')
>
> otherReducerName: otherReducerNameSlice.reducer,
>
> at Object. (src/redux/rootReducer.ts:28:47)
>
> at Object. (src/redux/store.ts:2:1)

I found the problem is the `errorReceived` which directory access the store object and dispatches an action.

```
store.dispatch(openErrorMessage({ message: errorMessage }));
```

How can I solve this problem of Jest giving `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reducer')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely means you have a circular import error, and the slice file hasn't loaded yet when the store is being initialized.

This is probably caused by importing the store directly into that `TestClass` file.  This is actually one of the reasons why [we specifically say you should *not* import the store directly into other files](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#only-one-redux-store-per-app).

Generally, you shouldn't be using classes like this in a Redux app in the first place. There's no real benefit or need to use them.

If you absolutely *must* reference the store (which should only be done as a last resort), we have [some suggestions on how to work around this](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-can-i-use-the-redux-store-in-non-component-files).